# Best pratice to check if a panel is open

Tags: jquery, slide

Is it better to use global variables or check the .css property (in the example I'm using visibility, but I would probably use width) to see if a panel is open/closed? Are there any drawbacks to using the global variant? It seems like a much more elegant, maintanable, reusable, faster and practical practice, but I have always been warned against using globals.

```
//Global//

var Panel;

function Slide()
{
    $('#panel').animate(
    {
        width:100%,
    },400,'easeInOutQuart');
    Panel='open';
}

function Check()
{
    if(Panel==='open')
    {
         //action//
    }
}
```

or

```
//CSS//

function Slide()
{
    $('#panel').animate(
    {
        width:100%,
    },400,'easeInOutQuart');
}

function Check()
{
    if($('#panel').is(':visible'))
    {
         //action//
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a class to the element and check for that class later. .hasClass is faster than `.is(':visible')` too

Comment: @Huangism It certainly seems better than using the slower check for property method, but what do you think about any of these two methods (css property and class) vs the global var method?

Comment: I have always used class, it's fast and does not require the making of a global variable. You can use .open or whatever makes sense to you. If you have to pick from css or global, it's more or less an opinion. I myself would probably use css

Comment: @Huangism Thanks. It seems this is merely a matter of opinion and convenience then. I guess it can be closed as not constructive.